# Need to show one particular view in App Delegate in a particular seconds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

while push notification receives need to show one particular view (push view) for 30 secs in AppDelegate after that it want to disappear.The whole project i did in storyboard.After clicking the button that was designed in a particular view(push view),Need to go home page that i designed in storyboard.

Comment: in - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo method write code to show view using Timer.

Answer (score 0):

First as usual, your first viewControler will be visible , whatever views are there on it. After you receive notification you can calll presentModalView controller and then after 30 seconds you can dismiss modal viewController. e.g 
(do this in didReceiveNotificationPart)

when received notification call:

```
[self presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

[self performSelector:@selector(dismissMyView) withObject:nil afterDelay:30];
```

for dismissing

```
-(void)dismissMyView
{

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] 

}
```